# Phase extraction from Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, dft, phase, frequency-domain

Is it possible in principle to correctly extract the phase from Fourier transform?

I just tried to do so using `Python`, here some attempts:

```
# attempt 1, phase=pi/2
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 1000
T = 1/fs
t = np.linspace(0,N*T, N)
N=len(t)

phase = np.pi/2
signal = 4*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t-phase)
FFT = np.fft.fft(signal)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(signal), T)

plt.plot(freqs[0:N//2], 2/N*np.abs(FFT[0:N//2]), label='amplitude')
plt.plot(freqs[0:N//2], np.angle(FFT[0:N//2]), label='phase')

plt.axhline(phase, color='k', linestyle='--', label='phase value')

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

which outputs:

[image]

zoomed-in:

[image]

The first question that comes to my mind - why does the phase so blurred (why it is not just one point as for the amplitude spectrum?)

if I try another phase:

```
fs = 1000
T = 1/fs
t = np.linspace(0,N*T, N)
N=len(t)

phase = -np.pi/8
signal = 4*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t-phase)
FFT = np.fft.fft(signal)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(signal), T)

plt.plot(freqs[0:N//2], 2/N*np.abs(FFT[0:N//2]), label='amplitude')
plt.plot(freqs[0:N//2], np.angle(FFT[0:N//2]), label='phase')

plt.axhline(phase, color='k', linestyle='--', label='phase value')

plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

it outputs:

[image]

The second question that I have - why does the phase exist in the whole frequency range, not only the frequency I'm interested in?

According to these examples I can't extract exact phase of original signal, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the DFT at the frequency of the input signal.

I recommend doing this experiment with the DTFT instead of the DFT. You can implement it in just a few lines of code, and unless the signal is very long, it will still be calculated very quickly on modern computers.

Then, if the input signal is $x[n] = \cos(2\pi f_0 kT_s + \phi)$ and its DTFT is $X(f)$, then $\angle X(f_0) = \phi$.

Example code, in Julia, that illustrates estimating the phase of a single sinusoid using the DTFT:

```
fs = 1000
ts = 1/fs
t = range(0, 1-ts, step=ts)
# signal parameters
A = 4       # amplitude
f0 = 10     # frequency
phi = -pi/8 # phase
signal = A*cos.(2*pi*f0*t .+ phi)
# DTFT evaluated at f = f0
dtft_tone = exp.(-2im*pi*f0*t)
dtft_f0 = (1/length(t))*sum(signal .* dtft_tone)
# estimate parameters
A_est = 2*abs(dtft_f0)   # 4.0
phi_est = angle(dtft_f0) # -0.3927 == -pi/8
```

Now, change the analysis frequency:

```
dtft_tone = exp.(-2im*pi*20*t)
```

Here we're calculating the amplitude and phase of the signal at frequency 20. Both should be zero. However, we get an amplitude of `5.770404116019941e-16` and a phase of `1.1063743245570448`. The amplitude is not zero due to numerical inaccuracy in the calculation, which is essentially unavoidable. In consequence, we also get a phase measurement, but it is meaningless.

One way out of it is to "zero" all DTFT (or DFT) measurements with an amplitude less than a threshold, say `1e-6`. In your code, you would go through every element of `FFT` and force to zero those that are too small.

Comment: ok, thank you for advice! but how can I interpret the result that I plotted? why does the phase have such a behaviour?

Comment: Probably because the amplitude of the FFT at other frequencies is not exactly zero, due to numerical inaccuracy in the floating point operations, and/or because you're not analyzing an integer number of periods of the sine wave (it's hard to tell from your code what the value of `N` is).

Comment: ok, I'll look through it, thank you!) by the way, do you know how to calculate frequencies in DTFT? I tried the `Python` module `pydsm` and calculated DTFT of my signal, but the frequencies from DFT are incorrect((

Comment: Is it possible they're using normalized frequencies? Many libraries measure frequencies in radians per sample, which are in the range from `-pi` to `pi`. It's a simple matter to map those to hertz in the range from `-fs/2` to `fs/2`.

Comment: I found the formula for the frequency: $\omega_k=\frac{2\pi k}{N}$ for $k=0,...,N-1$, but the result is still weird((

Comment: and are you sure that DTFT is good for using in computers? some books write that it is not a good idea, recommended method is DFT instead

Comment: I use it all the time, because usually I want to sample the spectrum at specific frequencies, not just at those the DFT gives me. Why do they say it's not a good idea? Of course it's much slower than the DFT, but for moderate-size signals that's not a problem.

Comment: becuase of the infinite number of sinusoids required for correct DTFT synthesis

Comment: But you don't need synthesis. You just need the value of the DTFT at a specific frequency.

Comment: ok, in principle I see that even `np.angle` gives more or less correct phase at the frequency of interest (which I know from the amplitude spectrum) and the phase at all the other frequencies is just the result of some kind of round-off error, but it doesn't look noisy, it looks very smooth instead...

Comment: I've added some code and further explanation to my answer. And you're right: the numerical error does not behave like typical noise, maybe contrary to intuition.

Comment: I see, thank you for that! Could you please clarify the frequency range? I'd like to plot the whole phase spectrum; am I right, that the fundamental frequency here is $2\pi\frac{fs}{N}$?

Comment: Just make `f0` vary between `-fs/2` and `fs/2` in whatever resolution (step size) you want.

Comment: ok, thank you! I've ploted the phase spectrum using DTFT and it again looks very smooth in the whole frequency range (the value at the frequency of interest is correct), does it really round-off error... so smooth and without any random noise...

Comment: Make sure to use a very fine resolution (say, 5000 frequency samples), and you'll see more erratic behavior. Still, it's not quite noise, but there's no reason it should be.

Comment: I tried different thresholds to "zero" data and found that it works as it should be from the values of ~ >5e-2, but the general tendency is clear for me know, thank you!